# how to shift the key focus between two clutter_actors?

Tags: c, gtk, gnome, clutter

Hi i have two clutter_actors . when i shift the focus from actor_1 to actor_2 for the first time it works. but later it does not shift back. I use the following statements.

```
clutter_stage_set_key_focus (CLUTTER_STAGE(stage), actor_2);
g_signal_connect (actor_1, "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK (button_key_press), NULL);
clutter_actor_set_reactive (actor_2, TRUE);
```

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you mean when you run the application and change focus through inputs, the focus does not change? Programmatically what ever piece of code you have shared, sets the focus to `actor_2`. Also is `actor_1` in `g_signal_connect` a typo?

Comment: the above code only shifts the focus to actor_2. The code is just to show that i use these many steps to shift the focus. My question is what extra should i do to put the focus on an actor which already had the focus before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

It was very easy. Its the same code i have used which i have given in the question.

Actually i was giving the key focus to actor_2 when i wanted to shift the focus from actor_2 to actor_1 . It was a logical error from my side.